# How to Customize the Data Entry Form of my List in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

How will i able to do something like in the image below in my form using Sharepoint 2013 or Sharepoint Designer 2013?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, I'll create multiple views in infopath and switch the view based on workflow status.

You could check below thread for sample.

https://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/how-to-create-multiple-views-in-infopath/

Comment: I will try this one. Thanks for the info! :)